# Sudden stop in consumption of messages from ActiveMQ

Tags: api, wso2, queue, activemq-classic, consumer

I am facing a problem that my proxy service in WSO2 is up and running, but it stops consuming messages from ActiveMQ queue for few minutes, and then suddenly start to consume again. There are no errors shown, it just stops, queue builds, and suddenly starts to consume again. Sometimes this issue is for 1 or 2 minutes or sometimes 5 or 6 minutes too. The time is variable. I tried to look into trends, but there are no trends.

Regarding the connectivity and network, in the same project there is another proxy service which is consuming another queue on same ActiveMQ server, and it is working absolutely fine with no issues.

Any guidance on why this can occur would mean a lot.

Comment: Did you check how long the message took to process when you saw the delay?

Comment: Standard operating procedure here is to gather thread dumps from the consuming application when the delay occurs. If the consumer is busy (e.g. in a blocking call to a database, HTTP webservice, high-CPU task, etc.) that will show up in the thread dumps. If there are no consumer threads in the thread dump that indicates a potential problem with the network or the broker. Given your description it seems like a problem with the consumer and not the broker or the network.

Comment: Any feedback here? Did you ever get this sorted?

Comment: Hi @JustinBertram this kind of issue is happening again. Their is one car file of micro integrator having 2 proxy service, 1 of them is consuming and pushing to new queue correctly but the next one is not consuming. There are no errors no connectivity issues nothing

Comment: Did you gather thread dumps from the consuming application(s)? If so, what did they reveal? If not, why not? Is this related to [your other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77686891)?

Comment: Attaching to process ID 35, please wait...
Debugger attached successfully.
Server compiler detected.
JVM version is 11.0.10+9
Deadlock Detection:

Can't print deadlocks:VM.initialize() was not yet called


I am getting this tried jstack pid > threadump command

Comment: And yes @JustinBertram but in the other scenario the situation was for long I guess 1 or 2 hours. again for context same car file has 2 proxy service one is perfectly consuming and pushing the message on activemq but the other proxy service isnt.