# ActiveMQ Classic Consumption issue

Tags: queue, activemq-classic, wso2-micro-integrator

I have 2 servers consuming a queue from ActiveMQ Classic 5.17.2. Suddenly one server crashed and stopped consuming. However, the other server kept working fine. The time when server stopped there were few messages in queue and they got stuck. New messages were consuming fine (a little slow), but older ones remained stuck.

Even when I started my DR Servers there wasn't any impact in the speed of consumption of the messages rather the number stayed the same. Can anyone of you guide what can be the issue?

By the way I was using wso2 MI's microservices to consume the messages

Comment: @JustinBertram 5.17.2

Comment: Are you using XA transactions?

Comment: What role do your "DR servers" play here?

Comment: @JustinBertram dr server is up and running when the other server crashes

Comment: @JustinBertram I tried to replicate the scenario, the situation is that once the 2nd server crashes the consumption on 1st server also slows down big time. Its like 10 15 messages are consumed then 2 3 minutes pause then 5 messages then 3 4 mins pause. Where consumers are showing on activemq front end agains the queue