# ActiveMQ Consumption issue in wso2 MI

Tags: docker, wso2, queue, activemq-classic, wso2-micro-integrator

I have 2 servers running which are consuming messages from activemq queues, server 2 crashes due to some issues (high mem consumption) because of which the queue is now being consumed at one server. This reduces the speed of consumption big time, like now the message despite having 75 consumers consumes 10 15 messages then after gap of 1 min consume 5 10 messages then after 25 30 seconds consumer few hundred. However, prior to crash in server it was working absolutely fine. And even if we gracefully shut down the server the consumption on other node remained absolutely fine. I am unable to understand the reason behind it and how can it be resolved. For info I am using wso2 MI proxy service to consume the messages which is running on a docker container.

I am attaching a screenshot of messages enqueued and consumers active below

I had also asked same type of question earlier too.

[ActiveMQ Classic Consumption issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77686891/activemq-classic-consumption-issue)

[image: This is screenshot of the queues you can clearly see that consumers are showing there]

Comment: Have you enabled message coordination?

Comment: @ycr how do we enable message coordination

Comment: Message coordination is not available for Proxies AFAIK, I think you are better off using Inbound Endpoints instead of proxy services. https://ei.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/micro-integrator/references/synapse-properties/inbound-endpoints/polling-inbound-endpoints/jms-inbound-endpoint-properties/